# Solving the output for recursion being used in linkedlist

Tags: java, recursion

I was given, in order to prepare for my exams, the following:

1. A java class with an executable static void main as follows:

   ```
   public class TestNode{
       public static mystery (Node root){
           if(root == null){return;}

           if(root.data%2==0 || root.data<2){
               mystery(root.left);
           }
           System.out.println(root.data);

           if(root.data%2==1 || root.data>3){
               mystery(root.right);
           }
           System.out.println(root.data);

       }

       public static void main (String[] args){

           System.out.println(mystery(root));

       }

   }
   ```

2) A set of data as depicted here: [tree diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYDzS.png).

I need to determine the output on Standard-Out of the application of point 1 if i was to give as argument the tree of data of point 2.

How can I go about solving this problem?

Comment: You need to create a `Node` object to pass into the `mystery()` function. Most likely this node will be the root of a tree.

Comment: You proceed by declaring the `Node` class, then create the 10 `Node` objects to build the tree in the diagram you linked to.

Comment: @Toby your question is not very clear: did I understand correctly if I say that you were required to choose the correct root node on the tree depicted at https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYDzS.png in order to make your recursive function `mystery(root)` succeed?

Comment: How can I solve this without the use of any programming and just the tree diagram and the code provided?

Comment: @ Katuiros  question is: what is the output if we call mystery(root) where root is shown in the diagram

Comment: @Toby are you sure that you were give a code like this? the function `mystery` does not provide a return type!

Comment: @Katuiros did you check the diagram I posted? I think you have to use that to determine the output

Comment: yes, I have checked but the code that was given to you is visibly not complete and will not work if run in java because `mystery` function does not have a return type

Comment: @Katuiros not supposed to use java for this, it's a logic problem that uses recursion. Solve with hand apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To walk you through the beginning of the process the logic here is as follows: You begin with a call of mystery(1). Since 1  < 2 you enter the first if statement and run mystery(root.left) which in this diagram is mystery(3). Since 3 is an even number and greater than 2, you skip the first if statement and print out 3. You then enter the second if statement and call mystery(2). This enters the first if statement (as its even) and calls mystery(9). This first prints 9, and then since 9 is odd enters the second if statement and tries to call mystery(9.right). As the node is null it returns right away and here your recursion starts to unwind. It prints 9 again and then you jump back to the mystery(2) call and print 2 two times (Once for each print statement after the if statements).

This continues to unwind and you can walk through the entire thing, but the important point to note is that each node will be printing twice when its called, the question is just when it prints. It's also important to point out that some calls will enter both if statements such as when its an even number greater than 3.

Comment: Thank you, clear logical explanation! So this program will output 3 because that is the first print I'm assuming? Or will it run the course, and print everything out till it's complete?

Comment: @A.K. did you realise that his code is actually broken? 

`mystery` does not have a return type first of all.

Comment: @Katuiros I was assuming a void return type and that the question was just about what will be printed in the interim. But yes, it is not usable code. Toby- it will run its course until complete.